# How to fig font for SSIS Project

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I'm open SSIS Project in Windows Server 2016 and it show like this.
Can somebody help me know how to set font size.

SSIS :

[image]

Comment: Please do read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @bigeyesowl, was your question addressed?. If so,  can you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the question is about large fonts of connection managers.

This is a Visual Studio related issue. Some thoughts on things to check:

1. Review font settings: `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`
2. Check `Windows display settings -> Scale and Layout`, perhaps something like 200% was set.